# angular is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: installation, angular-cli

I have installed the angular and can see the details using **ng --version**.

[image: installed angular]

Now I want o build my angular project and so I navigate to my angular project which is located in **D:\Angular** and gives me error **'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I am confused as by running the ng --version it showing me the angular installed but not working when I tried to build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution and did following change

**ADD -> " C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm " to PATH in system variable**

All set !